# How to display places names when using Quantum GIS and shapefiles?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, geonames

I am new to the world of geo systems. What I would like to do is displaying some information on a map for given regions.

I downloaded shape files from cloud made web site and load layers using Quantum GIS. Now I would like to display the places names but I do not know how to do.

Are these information already present in the file how can I do to display them ?

If so, I guess It should be possible to do joins with the data I want to display.

Can you please help me on this subject ?

Comment: Could you define which places you want to label? "place names" is a bit vague.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To display labels on QGIS you can click on the menu on "Layer"->"Labelling".

Then you can choose the field name to display on your label. On recent versions of QGIS you can add modifiers and functions to the field content.

Then you set the options for the way it will be rendered : color, size, buffer...

You can see the data fields content with the attribute table : right click on your layer and select "Open attribute table"

If you want to display other informations on your map, you can add your layers on top of the OSM shapefile layer.