# Create a new map from scratch for qgis

Tags: qgis, google-earth

I want to create a map of my campus. I don't have an individual map of my campus which can support in qgis. I created a boundary of the map using google earth polygon tool and converted xml file to shp in qgis. but shp file shows attribute data empty. i want a map which also shows the location, say water bodies and various information in the map as it shows in google earth map. How can i do that any suggestion?

Comment: You want to add new fields to attribute table only ?

Comment: I want a map which shows the information at every location in the map. Currently my map shows nothing and has empty attribute data.

Comment: If you want to add data to your attribute table, here is the link http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/adding-attribute-data-to-shapefile  and after you add the fields you want, use the label property to show any field of you attribute as in this link http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22893/how-to-display-places-names-when-using-quantum-gis-and-shapefiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you start digitizing your entire campus, have a look on [Open Street Map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6933/downloading-openstreetmap-data) and see if any physical or topographical features are already mapped there. If so, you may want to consider basing your mapping on that.

Furthermore, simple digitizing from Google Earth doesn't let you import any attribute data besdies the label, You'll have to define a number of categorial field in QGIS for each polygon feature type (Point, Line, Polygon) and populate them manually.

It is useful to remember that you can also add the OSM, as well as Google, Bing, and other aerial/satellite basemaps directly in QGIS and digitize on top of that as a .shp right off the bat, without having to import data created in other GIS.